# Using reCAPTCHA on localhost with port

Tags: testing, localhost, port, recaptcha

**simple question** : is it possible to test google captcha on localhost with a port.

**simple example** : http://127.0.0.1:1986

— or DO we have to use the default port, thus setting up a *%&#@ proxy or messing up with all my local projects.. :(

thanks ♥︎

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the tests keys: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do

> **Site key**: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
>
> **Secret key**: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe

Comment: remind: Using test keys, you will always get No CAPTCHA and all verification requests will pass.

Comment: @NoobTW - for a noob you sure do provide a pretty important point. I mean if you can't diagnose failure ..